# What happened to the time portal in DS9 "Time's Orphan"?

Tags: star-trek, time-travel, star-trek-ds9

DS9 "Time's Orphan":

> DAX: It's some sort of **time portal**. From the chroniton signature, we
>   think it sent Molly about three hundred years into the past.

So the Federation now has it's hands on a bonafied time portal. O'Brien says he's going to destroy it, but we don't actually see him do it in the episode. They figured out how to get it working in a short period of time.

Remember the 24th century STU knows about the temporal prime directive, the prime directive police, etc. from multiple episodes throughout the various series, so they do know that they are eventually going to use the technology of time travel.

Did they study the portal further? Did O'Brien destroy it? Would the Federation really not use and study this technology once they got their hands on it?

Writer's notes, director's notes, EU info is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the TV and film canon there are no further mentions however according to a throwaway line in the trek novel "[Star Trek: Department of Temporal Investigations: Watching the Clock](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Watching_the_Clock)", the portals were taken into the care of the Dept of Temporal Investigations and placed in a large, impregnable vault to prevent their further use except in exceptional circumstances:

> Lucsly turned to see Director Andos standing in the door of the AD’s
>   office that had formerly been hers. “Agent Lucsly. Agent Dulmur. Would
>   you join me, please?” she asked. Her manner was reserved, contained,
>   but overpowering in its authority. Kreinns nodded at her and moved
>   away, and Lucsly and Dulmur silently filed into the office.
>
> Only it wasn’t the office. **Lucsly whirled around, recognizing the
>   cavernous space surrounding him from his multiple visits here, most
>   recently to secure the last of the ancient time portals excavated on
>   the Bajoran colony world Golana over the past three years. He, Dulmur,
>   and Andos were in the Eridian Vault.**